# What is the difference between using AddDbContextPool and using IDesignTimeContextFactory?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

From my limited understanding, they appear to serve a similar purpose when starting with a code-first approach; am I correct in that thinking? If I'm not correct, when would you use one over the other?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about AddDbContextPool versus IDesignTimeDbContextFactory? I doubt there is AddNewDbContextPool and IDesignTimeContextFactory.

Comment: AddDbContextPool is used to pool DbContexts to avoid creating new instances every time (just like old connection pooling).
  

IDesignTimeDbContextFactory is used to help design-time services such as ef migration in creating DbContext instances, especially when DbContext  does not have a default co constructor. Basically this interface is applicable only during design-time.